# Changing hasMany relationship in old app Laravel 4.2 to data from an array

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have been given an older (v4.2) Laravel app to modify.  The application was pulling "credits" for a rep via Eloquent and need to now get them from an API which returns them in a JSON array.

In the blade I am seeing `{{round($rep->credits->sum('Credits'), 2)}}`

**Rep Model**

```
class Rep extends \Eloquent {    
     public function credits() {
                return   $this->hasMany('Repcredit', 'RepNumber');
        
    }
}
```

I *tried* Rep Model to :

```
 class Rep extends \Eloquent {    
    public function credits() {
        $searchParam = [
        "apiId" => 7438,    "data"     => [
                "RepNumber" => $this->attributes['id'],
            ]
        ];
        $result = (new ApiCallerController)->apiSearch($searchParam);
        $result = $result['data'];


        this return the correct data in an array
        | RepNumber | CreditDate    | Credits
        | -------- | -------------- |
        | 51       | 2021-06-01     |  5.21
        | 52       | 2021-06-01     |  6.32
        | 51       | 2021-06-04     |  2.87

            
        return $result;
     }
}
```

But then I get an error 1Relationship method must return an object of type `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\Relation (View: /var/www/html/app/views/reps/show.blade.php)`

I changed the return to `return $this->hasMany($result, 'RepNumber');` and now I am getting an error
`Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Collection::newQuery()`

It seems there is a lot of resources for newer versions of Laravel but since I am unable to upgrade from v4.2 I am not able to find any good examples of how to go about this.

Can anyone give me a good push in the right direction?

Comment: First of all, you can't pass anything other than the related class (as string) in the `hasMany` as the first parameter, because `Laravel` creates an instance of that model from the class to get a new `Eloquent Query Builder`. Secondly, instead of upgrading to the latest version at once, try to upgrade step by step, which means, at first upgrade to `v-5.0` then to the next version (5.1) and so on.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't use a `hasMany` relation in this case because your API returns a `collection` and from any relationship method, you've to return an instance of `Relation`.

Comment: I there a way to "convert" the collection of an instance of `Relation`?  Or some alternate strategy? As for the Slow upgrade Management has been very firm that we will be doing NO upgrading at least for the next few months so I am very handicapped there.

Comment: Finally, these relationship methods like `hasMany`, operate on database tables to make a relationship so you need tables for that. Even a temporary table should work. If you are using `mysql` then you may create a temporary table for that, maybe just maybe but not sure how good that would be.

Comment: Since you asked for a workaround, so maybe you can try to create a temporary table inside the relationship method `credits` and fill it using the data received from the API call using the same related/foreign key and other required data. At last return the `hasMany` relation.

Comment: This is just an idea and to be honest I didn't try this practically so make sure you know what is going on. All the best. [Temporary Table](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-temporary-table/).

Comment: Actually may need to go that direction so thanks you have been helpful.